# Keep element inside visible part of window

Tags: css, css-float

I have positioned a sidebar element at the right side of the visible part of the screen (this part already works!). The sidebar consists of several DIVs. A few of them I don't care about, but the last (lowest) one should not "disappear" when the user scrolls down the page. And here is where I'm stuck. In a way, the top position should **not be < 0** of the visible top of the browser window. Is that even possible with CSS and the better browsers?

Here is my definition of the sidebar:

```
div#sidebar{font-size:95%; float: right;width: 150px; margin-top:20px;}
div#sidebar div{padding: 5px 0;margin-bottom: 5px}
```

Here is the element I would like to keep inside the visible part of the screen:

```
div#navtop{background:#B3B3E3 url(/css/blue.jpg); margin-bottom:0px;}
div#navsoc{background:#B3B3E3 url(/css/blue.jpg); margin-bottom:0px; top:!important 0px;}
```

The second element, "navsoc", should remain in the visible part. But it moves exactly like "navtop" and the others I have defined there.

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="navsoc">
keep me inside the window!
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need

```
position:fixed;
```

So the element will be positioned relatively to the window, so if you scroll it is always visible.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mJubt/

Moreover, if you want to set `!important` to a value, use `top:0!important` instead of `top:!important 0`.

And when you have `0px` you don't have to write the unit, you can use just `0`.

Comment: thanks, this way to code things worked exactly as intended in my own code that way too now - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

if you use `top` in CSS you should make sure that the element's `position` is not `static` (default) but `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. So, `top:0` in this case is not working. And if you do change the position to either of those it would behave in different ways:

if it's fixed the element would be position relative to the window
if it's relative or absolute it would be position `zero pixels` from the top of the closest element in the `DOM` with a position different than `static`.

If the contents of the element above `#navsoc` has a flexible height you can't make it respect it's position and at the same time not move on scroll.
You need Javascript to achieve that.

The first part is a bit off topic back I think it is good to know it!

Here you have the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEXkK/1/).

Comment: For some reason, the element didn't move down in relation to the floating text in this example, but I guess I did something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/dEXkK/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this thread because I did not know what search-term to use for this behavior.

And since a decade ago there seems to have been an improvement in web-technology  and we now have `position: sticky`

```css
.sticky-to-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```